# Demolish a string!

Tags: code-golf, string, random

## Challenge

Given a string input, output the demolished version of it.

## The Process

```
P
r      Pr       r
o       o       o
g       g       g
r       r       r      rogr         r
a  ->   a  ->   a  ->     a  ->     a  ->           ->           ->           ->           ->  
m       m       m         m         m
m       m       m         m         m         mmar         m
i       i       i         i         i         i            i           mi           m
n       n       n         n        gn        gn           gn           gn           gni         mgni
g       g      Pg        Pg      roPg      roPg         roPgmar      roPgmar      roPgmar      roPgmar
```

1. Place the string vertically.
2. Select a random integer between `1` and `(height of the column of characters) - 1` and a random direction (left or right).
3. Rotate that number of characters in that direction (if those spaces are unoccupied go to step 4; if not, go back to step 2).
4. Let those characters fall due to gravity.
5. Repeat until the height of the column of characters is at most `1` larger than the height of the columns next to it (i.e. it becomes impossible to further demolish ("steps 2-4") the column).
6. If there is another column of characters that is more than `1` character taller than one or more of its surrounding columns (i.e. demolish-able), repeatedly demolish that column until it is no longer demolish-able. If there are multiple demolish-able columns, completely demolish the tallest column (if there are multiple tallest columns, completely demolish the leftmost one).
7. Repeat until all columns are no longer demolish-able.

If there are space characters in the input, demolish those first, all at once.

```
C
o

d      
e  ->     oC  ->         ->  ...
       de         
G        G          G
o        o          o
l        l          l
f        f        defoC
```

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Trailing and leading newlines are allowed.
- Your program may either print or return a string/equivalent.
- The output must be non-deterministic (unless the input is not demolish-able).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submissions with the smallest byte counts in their languages win!

Comment: I would doubt if random is really necessary here

Comment: @KeyuGan I think the challenge would be fairly trivial if people had to select a fixed number of characters and alternated left/right.

Comment: We still can say that 4 is random and returned by a fair dice roll

Comment: @someone `4` would make the output deterministic, i.e. not "random." Edited the rules to make that explicit.

Comment: @someone are you referring at 4 because of [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/221/)?

Comment: Yes, but that reference is not the main idea of the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>622</s> <s>595</s> <s>573</s> <s>552</s> <s>542</s> <s>534</s> <s>527</s> <s>520</s> 515 bytes

```python
from random import*
s=input()
r=range
R=choice
Z=len
L=h=Z(s)
a=[[]for _ in'  '*-~h]
S=s[::-1].split()
X=-1,1
for w in S[1:]:
 for i in r(Z(w)):a[h-~i*R(X)]+=w[i]
a[h]+=S[0]
while L:
 H=[map(Z,a[c-1:c+2])+[c]for c in r(1,h-~h)];D=L=[(min(n,m)-C,i)for n,C,m,i in H if~-C>min(n,m)]
 while D:
	_,c=min(L);n,C,m=map(Z,a[c-1:c+2]);D=X[n+2>C:1+(C-1>m)]
	if D:
	 d=R(D);l=R(r(1,C-[0,m,n][d]));w,a[c]=a[c][-l:],a[c][:-l]
	 for i in r(l):a[c-~i*d]+=w[i]
for l in zip(*[l+[' ']*max(H)[1]for l in a if l])[::-1]:print`l`[2::5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVKxjuMgEK2Xr6Az2LBaIl1DRBqnSJFilTRRRmjXwnaMhLGFs/Jdivx6Dhzt6aRtGJj35r1hYPxz7Qa/ejzaMPQ4VL6OwfbjEK45mpT149eVUBRUhC4NOijTDdY06Kxc49FedepMJooqBaDbIeAPbH2GcZbze6fRUU0gJRf6dRqdTUInxQUTKFHnSMVHEFJLhFPCpkQgZzJTKivo@N3mB3KiulAzWI1iKm6P8KbR3FnX4H0s3Cnoq5GcWQWGC2mKlaYFmKUZ8xQULEp1VK@3aq@A9NYTz3rKS2ZponlWsp4t7jts2zsvN98cjfDTaivRywczKgF7ul5K1A/j6HACX6w2pRQFKbnYJIkX2y71uFYHsqVrF0PqquTwFo29hlpTup6TklZpAe6kXo4guYsK/8/HpeGYNJz6ezIJdQm92ZHk4ArIcKbzvvpNdhSE/odX8X7Yafp8FTkG66@f7hNWUv7Sj0f2HoZLqPp4ywsev24310w4/glshrrBl8G12V8)

Comment: [527 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVI7b6swFJ7rX@EtNuCqIN3FyFnIkIGhapYoR0ctMhAsGYMgFb0Z@tdzbaJWt@riY/t7nIc9/r10g8tut3YaejpVrvbB9OMwXSIyK@PG9wvjZFIeOjfkReluMLohJ2UbR0rVqRObOakUALbDRF@pcRu6icRnF2VIDmoGKUWKj/NoTXA6KhBpkiIJ7MWz6QFSiZLQWr2wIyc0ACYAEzuxhXNZQRfX3tFgrBYwSPyF3x7gCcnSGdvQ0sv3CvpqZKekAi1SqeMMeQx6rUrf7dKk83VxzEsFrDeOuaTnokgMDySXFEmfrJn31LSfoth@cTDfqZLQe7KdJA@viVYBLHm@ytSv1F5xBBdn20KmMStEuvU25MG0q35tdsdz60OoqxDw5JM7hBo5z5fghCosIKzE9QhSWO/w/3xsGI7@OZwA2wBfzcgisDH498Corz7YnkOK33jlm6QW@f2B5DgZd3mzb5BJ@Qdvt83zNJynqvdtnun4fr3aZqb@f1A91A09D7bd/AM)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks :)

Comment: [520 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVI9b@sgFJ3Lr2AL2FDVlt6CRRZnyOChSpYoV6i1sB0jYWzhVH4vQ/96Co76VKkLF@6559wvpn/XfnT5/d75ccC@dk0wZphGf03QLI2bPq6EIi8DdGnRQep@NLpFZ2lbhyrZyzOZKaolgOpGj9@wcRu8Sfhnn@QKHeUMQvBMPc@TNVHpJHnGMhRjlxCLj5AJJRCODhMdnpzJQqmooU8P5ESDlFGpXMAoFHzheoQXhZbe2BZXgbmXMNQTObMaNM@ETnNFU9BrOfqhmLE@FERVUUkgg3HEsYHykhkagxwr2cDW5Htsuk9ebr9jVLGTFcKPZDuBnt6YlhGsaLHS5K/UgXECl@bbUmQpKXm2DTLoyXQrHzfyQHa0sMHEukoOLyG5U9AoSoslKikZD@BWqPUJgtug8HNENs5Hp83P4UTYRvhmJpKATSEsQiVD/ZfsKWTqP16HJrFV9LEZMXnjru/2HXIh/qj7ffPqx4uvh9DmBU8ft5ttZxw@BtZj0@LLaLvNFw)

Comment: `h+R(X)*-~i` can be `h-~i*R(X)`.

Comment: `L=[...];D=L` can be `D=L=[...]`.

Comment: `' '*-~h*2` can be `-~h*'  '` (the string contains two spaces).

Comment: [515 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVKxjuMgEK3XX0FnsOEUR9oGizROkZNSrJImygjtWjaOkTC2sCPvpciv58DZXZ10DQPz5r03DAx/pra360etGvTbDtcJEz4qVeMVyZ2ars4i/Uw/Gtd3yJW29kF3Q@@mJB@powd6Fl9U6uGLolXb60pRo2y@F60445HkJT0KANn0Dr17yRihOGH3VtIROGeZ/DUORnuJ/CRYRrMoFM6@EB0h45JHKCR0SDh8xjMhvISW3XVywCciUzGDlpFP@e0RVjKaW20U2nviTkBXDvhMS6hYxqt0LUkK1dJK9RTMqJdqicy3Yi8Ad9piSzvCCqpJKLO0oB1d3HdIN3dWbL5rZISeVlsevbzTSgRgT/KFIv4z9g4nsOl6U/AsxQXLNkHiRTcLH9XigLckNz6ErgoGK29sJdSSkHwOSlKEBZjhcjkCZ8Yr/DsfE4ZTheHU35MJqAnoTQ84AZNCjGKZdOUn3hHI5A9e@vshI8nzVfjgtJ0@zAesOX@Vj0f85vqLKzt/ywsarrebUSPyfwJVfa3QpTdN/Bc).